# image float left align middle

Tags: css

I have to put an image on left side of a table.  image must be floated left while aligning **vertically** to middle. It seems `margin auto` does not work for that. does anybody have any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/XDT9j/

```
 <div style="width:70%;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="float:left;">


         <img width="128" height="128" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/image" 
style="margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;"/>
            </div>
            <div>
            <table>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no </img> tag. It self closes. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element

Comment: i used that for jsfiddle editor not to show red </div> to me. it has not effect to my issue.

Comment: It SELF-CLOSES. You still have not closed it (`<img .... />`) If you close it, you won't see red <div> on jsFiddle, that are warnings, not bad behaviors to try to bypass.

Comment: corrected. thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing some useless HTML, simply use `vertical-align: middle;` together with `display: inline-block;` on both the `<img>` and the `<table>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7SRgh/

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv" >   
        <img id="myImg"  src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/image" />


        <table>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myDiv table, #myImg {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#myDiv {
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px dashed silver;
}

#myImg {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this all with tables.

```
<div style="width:70%;">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   <img width="128" height="128" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/image" />
</td>
<td>
    <table>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1</td><td>col 2</td><td>col 3</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td></tr></table>
 </div>
```

Comment: the problem is that at first it was a table and i'm migrating from tables to div. tables have troubles with responsive design.

Comment: using table for none-tabular data should always be avoided since it is none-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin-top: 50%; and it will align your image vertically on middle.

Comment: thanks. it didnt go to exactly vertical middle. but approaches to what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/BGRw2/8/

Comment: it goes to 50% of total page not parent div!